# Android application crash reported by google play crash report

Tags: android

I got a below crash report in my android application from google play

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:625)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:258)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:229)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:336)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am not sure if its my coding mistake or its a Android bug.
Could you please help me in understanding this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Based on my knwledge "Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" this shows u r accessing a context using StartActivity() from outside so u must set the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: @Arju Looking at the stack trace it doesn't look there is any of OP's code in there. That's all Android components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a flag missing in your intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this helps .... Cheers!

Comment: Ok... but if that flag is must, why did not it crashed each time the app started. Why it has crashed now?, i mean there are around 3500 downloads, and the crash has happened now?.. What is the purpose of the flag?

Comment: Are there any conditions around your `startActivity()` call? What is the calling context? Do you start the activity always from another activity?

Comment: @Santosh it differ from some devices to others. mostly "custom roms" and china phones will cause this kind of things :D. the thing that i hate about android is . there is no insurance that your app will work on every android device. so bad tho

Comment: @StyleMe: if there is no `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`, `Thread`, ... that calls this activity - may be it's due to a custom ROM